# Android: Firebase Cloud Messaging run code before showing notification to filter messages

Tags: android, firebase, filter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an application for my College:

Users (students) login on it with their college credentials, once they are authenticated, the app creates a Firebase Database data for that user containing al his info, including the disciplines(subjects) that he is on course.

Then comes the Firebase Cloud Messaging part, the users can send notifications for other users that are on the same disciplines.

Example: I'm coursing Math, then can I send a notification to the others users that are also doing Math. There are hundreds of disciplines in my College.

My idea is to send the notification to all of my app's users then, before notifying, handle with some code to check if the user is registered to the notification's target discipline or not, if he is, send notification, else, do not send anything, in others words, filter the message before showing the notification!

I studied several Firebase Cloud Messaging docs and examples but I couldn't find a way how to do it... Can somebody give a light?

Comment: That all sounds very possible. I'd probably use a topic for each discipline, and then check on a trusted environment (i.e. a server you control, or Cloud Functions) for the membership before calling the API to send a message to the topic: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic. What specific step are you stuck on?

Comment: I already codded the FCM services and I can receive notification sent from Firebase console

I'm now trying to figure out how to filter the messages before codding to send from the app

But my idea of sending to everyone and filter before showing the notification in the bar is not possible, right?

Comment: It's possible to suppress on the client, as long as you send data messages. But since you already have all the information to determine who won't show it, why would you send a notification to those users (draining their battery and bandwidth) to begin with?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've followed your advice and did it by topics, perfect solution! I'm having some trouble now how to send the data and conditions  of notifications json, I can do that using ARC and filling json manually and I can retrieve that on the app, but I have no idea how to send it from the app (I can send normal msgs using Retrofit)

The data will contain all information I need to fill in the notification and condition will be the topics

Comment: Sending messages *to* a device requires that your specific the FCM server key. As its name implies this key should only be used on a server (or otherwise trusted environment), because knowing it allows someone to send messages on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually, it'd be best to decide server-side on the group of users that will receive the notification, meaning, you need to have them in some sort of group. Firebase has a concept of group and subscription for messaging. And you can setup a cloud function to actually send the message to the clients

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple

Comment: Below is the json struture of my FB realtime database, I want to send a notification to target discipline code YAD184 that reachs everyone that is registered to it, what exaclty I have to change in my structure or logic I have to use to reach that?
"usuarios" : {
    "396728406sp" : {
      "curso" : "ADS",
      "disciplinas" : {
        "YAD184" : {
          "codigo" : "YAD184",
          "cursoId" : 24,
          "nome" : "Math",
        }